# GSON: fromJson(Reader json, Type typeOfT) vs fromJson(String json, Type typeOfT)

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm working with a code base that takes the body of a network response and feeds it to a GSON instance with `fromJson(Reader json, Type typeOfT)` to create POJOs.

Usually I'll see a call to `fromJson(String json, Type typeOfT)` but they're adamant that using the `Reader` call is better.

What's the difference between using `String` vs `Reader` and how much of a difference would it make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reader` is a class that you use for reading stream of characters. So when the parser uses it, it takes each character one by one from the Reader and parse the input gradually.

Using a String forces you to store the all json into it before parsing. If you have a huge structure to parse, this might not be the optimal way to do it.

Also if you get the response from a request that you read in a Reader, it permits you to directly parse the response instead of reading all the stream to build it into a String and then feed this String into the parser.

So if you have the json directly in the String, use `fromJson(String s, ...)` otherwise use `fromJson(Reader r, ...)`

For a pratical example, let's say you have a huge json file that you want to parse but that has a syntax error on the first line. Reading all its content into a String for then parsing it to see that there is an error at the first line is obviously inefficient. 
If you used a `FileReader` instead, you would have just read the first line to see that this is a malformed json.